# Pass Movable Type variable from one page to another

Tags: variables, url, get, movabletype

I have an events page for the site in question, where the date, time, location, etc. of each event are listed in a table row.  See [here](http://www.weillcornell.org/prc/blog/events.php).

Each event is actually an "entry" in Movable Type, and the time, location, etc. are custom fields.  Everything so far works fine.  Now, when a user clicks on rsvp, I'd like to take the user to a simple rsvp form.  Currently, I have a `rsvp.php?eid=..` arrangement going, where the event id is passed in the URL.  This is one way, using PHP, to pass the event id from one page (events.php) to another (rsvp.php).  The problem arises when I try to access this value via Movable Type.  Because Movable Type is processed first, before PHP server-side, I'm having trouble querying Movable Type and outputting the event information (on rsvp.php) for the event whose id is listed in the URL.

Essentially, I need a way to keep track of the event, stored in Movable Type, as I move from one page to another.

Answer (score 0):

You could either publish rsvp.php with MT too, and have it publish a PHP array with information on all the events directly in the PHP code, so you can simply look up the event by ID in that array and use the data from there.  Note that this solution is not workable if you plan on having a huge number of events (hundreds or more) that can be rsvp'd to at the same time, as the list will grow too big and it might slow down rsvp.php.

Or you could publish a second entry archive for each event, with a predictable file name containing the ID of the event.  This second entry archive would then contain some PHP code that would set some variables with the event's information.  In rsvp.php you could then look at the id you were passed and based on that php-include the right file.  This way, rsvp.php would remain the same size.  (Do be careful to check the value of the passed id though, making sure it is numeric and all that so you don't get hacked by someone passing you a "funny" id which would cause your script to include a malicious file.)

Disclosure: I'm the author of the [movabletips.com](http://movabletips.com) blog.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  For the first alternative, would I need multiple arrays to account for location, time, date, etc? For example, have one array for time, another for location, and so on.  Or did you have something else in mind?  As for the second option, I'm still not very familiar with archive templates.  How would I distinguish between the Entry archive template I have now and a second one I create? In other words, how would I tell MT which one to use, depending on the circumstances? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The first method that Maarten mentioned above could work if you create an array for each and every event contains that given event details.

The second method that Maarten mentioned is that you could publish an extra 'Entry' archive for each event, assuming that you're creating each event as an entry inside a section called say 'Events'.

When I look at your site I would assume that you have an 'Events' section, you create each event as an entry and then you're generating:

1) an index template at:
http://www.weillcornell.org/prc/events.php

2) an individual template which publishes say at:
http://www.weillcornell.org/prc/events/caring-for-our-feet.php

But you could create an additional entry template which to still publish a file name like "10006.php" for the event sample I've invoked above and this file will contain the event data as an array.

Then, when you invoke the event reservation from:
http://www.weillcornell.org/prc/rsvp.php?eid=10006

In reality, instead of having all the events arrays inside the 'rvsp.php' file and thus produce a large 'rsvp.php' file, you could set the 'rsvp.php' file to simply include the file '10006.php' and extract the data from inside that single event array.

Hope this clarifies it.